# How to clear Visual Studio workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a workspace in VS2015 (same problem in 2013) that I'm trying to completely remove and start fresh with a copy from the server. To clarify, I want *none* of the files or changes that currently exist and I want to start *completely fresh* with the server copy of all files. I don't know how to correctly do this, however. I've deleted the workspace, the actual files that the workspace pointed to, and I've cleared the cache locations below, but VS still shows that the workspace exists and won't fix itself. In fact, it still shows the mapping even though I've triple-checked that it's deleted.

I'd like to avoid using `devenv /reset` since I'm pretty customized and I don't want to fix all of it, but I'll do it if it's unavoidable. How can I accomplish this?

Locations cleared/deleted:

```
%LocalAppData%\Temp\<all VS files/folders>
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the window where you can get a specific change set from TFS, get the changeset with id "1". This is the situation just before the project was created - empty!

- Right mouse om project node in solution explorer
- Source Control > Get specific version
- Version type "change set"
- Input change number "1" (without quotes)
- Click "Get"

Comment: Changeset 0 can't be pulled (`Get` button is grayed out), but I was able to pull ID 1 and that was exactly what I needed. Thank you!